# Transaction with ROOM database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-architecture-components

I have a question about transactions in the ROOM database. Is it possible to use @Transaction annotiation outside the DAO objects?

I have complex object to save so I do it by a manager that calls many methods from different daos. But I want to rollback transaction if any method fails.

It works with

```
roomDB.runInTransaction { 
dao1.insert(object.object1)
dao2.insert(object.object2)
dao3.update(objec.object3)
}
```

And the second problem that I'm facing is not closed cursor. Sometimes I got such exception:

```
W/SQLiteCompiledSql: Releasing statement in a finalizer. Please ensure that you explicitly call close() on your cursor: DELETE FROM tableName WHERE status IN ( ?,? )
    net.sqlcipher.database.DatabaseObjectNotClosedException: Application did not close the cursor or database object that was opened here
```

Sample method that I'm using:

```
    @TypeConverters(NameConverter::class)
    @Query("UPDATE tableName SET status = :status, last_update_date = :updateDate , finish_date = :finishDate, problem_reason = :problemReason WHERE id = :id")
    fun updateStatus(id: Long, status: WorkerStatus, updateDate: Long, finishDate: Long?, problemReason: String?)
```

Do I need to add additional annotation to the method to close a cursor?

Thanks for any advice ;)